# How to I expand arguments in a Docker RUN command using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, dockerfile, nano-server

I have a Dockerfile that uses a Windows Nano Server base image and uses Powershell as shell:

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver
SHELL ["powershell"]
```

I now want to define a variable (or pass it in via `--build-arg`) using the `ARG` command and then use it in a `RUN` command, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried:

```
ARG mydir=tmp
RUN mkdir %mydir%
RUN mkdir $mydir
```

But none of these work.

How do I tell docker / powershell to expand my variable correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arguments passed to a Powershell command run via `RUN` are not substituted by Docker, but by Powershell itself. They are treated like normal environment variables by Powershell, so the correct syntax is:

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver
SHELL ["powershell"]
ARG mydir=tmp
RUN mkdir $env:mydir
```

So in the same way you can also expand normal environment variables:

```
RUN mkdir $env:LOCALAPPDATA\$env:mydir
```

Note that this is only valid within the context of a `RUN` command. With other Docker commands variables still expand using the normal notation:

```
COPY ./* $mydir
```

It's confusing on Windows/Powershell as on Linux containers using a `bash` shell the notation is the same in both cases.

Comment: This absolutely does not work in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very similar to GeorgS's but I had to create an `ENV` using the `ARG` in order to get this working e.g. `$env:ORACLE_BASE`

```
ARG ORACLE_BASE=C:/apps/oracle/
ENV ORACLE_BASE=${ORACLE_BASE}
COPY instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.17.0.0.0dbru.zip .
COPY instantclient-sqlplus-windows.x64-19.17.0.0.0dbru.zip .
RUN Expand-Archive -Path instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.17.0.0.0dbru.zip -DestinationPath $env:ORACLE_BASE ; \
    Expand-Archive -Path instantclient-sqlplus-windows.x64-19.17.0.0.0dbru.zip -DestinationPath $env:ORACLE_BASE ; \
    Remove-Item instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.17.0.0.0dbru.zip -Force ; \
    Remove-Item instantclient-sqlplus-windows.x64-19.17.0.0.0dbru.zip -Force
```